How to align the vertically rotated text to the bottom, respectively the same start point
I do have bars with vertically rotated text, but I would like to have this text aligned near the bottom of each bar.
Here You can find the example: https://newacf.samui-infotech.asia/sample-page/
I tried to find some other sources and solutions, but could not find what I am doing wrong.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let bars = document.querySelectorAll('.vbc-bar');

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                let bar = entry.target;
                let percentage = bar.getAttribute('data-percentage');
                bar.style.height = percentage + '%';

                let percentageText = bar.querySelector('.vbc-percentage');
                let currentPercentage = 0;
                let increment = setInterval(() => {
                    if (currentPercentage >= percentage) {
                        clearInterval(increment);
                    } else {
                        currentPercentage++;
                        percentageText.textContent = currentPercentage + '%';
                    }
                }, 20);

                observer.unobserve(bar);
            }
        });
    }, {
        threshold: 0.1
    });

    bars.forEach(bar => {
        observer.observe(bar);
    });
});
.vbc-bar-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    margin-left: 0.3rem;
}

.vbc-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 2s ease;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

.vbc-title {
    /*writing-mode: vertical-rl;*/
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

.vbc-percentage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
<div class="vbc-bar-container" id="vbc-bar-6677d489b49f0">
    <div class="vbc-bar animated" data-percentage="75" style="--height: 75%; height: 75%;">
        <span class="vbc-title">Sales Growth</span>
        <span class="vbc-percentage">75%</span>
    </div>
</div>



I appreciate any help.

https://dev.to/afif/how-to-correctly-position-rotated-text-using-css-1gjc

Add to "vbc-title" class a property:
width: 100%;



Thank You Taki Kauser, exactly what I needed.
